# Apostrophes replaced by &#39;

Tags: plugins, theme-development, translation, regex

I use a plugin for automatic posting of articles on social networks, and when I

send an article on Facebook or Twitter from my website, the apostrophes of my

articles are replaced by this: '

It is possible that the problem comes from the theme, but I am not sure.

I tried to do a "search and replace" to replace this code with an apostrophe

using a "regex" but it does not work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be coming from the font of the theme. Try using a different font on your site.